# How to add user to my bucket in IBM Cloud Object Storage

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-storage, ibm-cloud-iam

I have created a bucket which has some files. I want my team to access that bucket. I tried creating a policy and adding the users but still, the team can't see the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is that you need to invite the users in your team to your account. You can do that in the UI "Manage -> Access -> Users".

Your team member needs to accept the invitation to your account and should then be able to switch to your account using the account switcher on the top right of her/his UI.

Now you can follow these steps to give bucket permissions to the user(s) in your account: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-iam-bucket-permissions

Once you feel comfortable with this, you can have a look into IAM Access Groups. Using IAM Access Groups you don't need to manage each individual user in your team and add permissions to the user. With IAM Access Groups you add the necessary permissions to the group and then add all users that need these permissions to the group.

I hope this helped.